# subspace topology and strong topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a locally convex space and $Y$ is a subspace of the strong dual of $X$, is the induced topology on Y equivalent to the strong topology $b(Y,Y')$ on $Y$? If this is not correct, then on what spaces does the strong topology coincide with the initial topology?

Answer (score 4):

If $(Y,\tau)$ is any locally convex space then $\tau=\beta(Y,Y')$ is equivalent to barrelledness of $(Y,\tau)$. Hence your question is if every subspace of a strong dual $(X',\beta(X',X))$ endowed with the relative topology is barrelled. The answer is of course negative (every Hausdorff locally convex space is a subspace of a strong dual).

More impotant than fancy counterexamples is the non-obvious fact that topological properties like barrelledness or (the closely related) bornologicity of certain subspaces may characterize important anlytical properties. For example, a partial differential operator $P(\partial)$ on $\mathscr D'(\Omega)$ is surjective if and only if $P(-\partial)(\mathscr D(\Omega))$ (the range of the transposed operator) is a bornological subspace of $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ (I believe that you can replace bornologicity by barrelledness, but I'm not absolutely sure right now).

EDIT: As you also asked for positive cases: A very good class of locally convex spaces is that of LS-spaces, i.e., countable inductive limits of Banach spaces with *compact* linking maps (this contains all DFN-spaces=strong duals of nuclear Frechet spaces). In LS-spaces every *closed* subspace is ultrabornological and barrelled. This is due to José Sebastião e Silva (and therefore, such spaces are sometimes called Silva spaces). Of course, also *closed* subspaces of Frechet spaces are barrelled (this is much easier than the dual case).

Comment: Thank you very much, what about DFN- spaces?

Comment: Jochen thanks, that's what I was looking for

Comment: Can you please give a reference for the Silvia's theorem.

Comment: This is more or less explicit in the book of Meise and Vogt. I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: In Meise-Vogt it is a bit hidden, proposition 26.24 is essentially an equivalent statement (also the Baernstein lemma 26.26 is closely related). Explicitely, the theorem of Silva is stated in corollary 8.6.9 of the book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of Bonet and Perez-Carreras.

Comment: I really appreciate it, one more question does on DFN spaces Mackey topology and strong topology coincide?, if I understand correctly Bonet and Perez-Carreras 0.4.4 they do.

Comment: Yes they do. More precisely: If $X$ is a nuclear Frechet space then the Mackey topology $\tau(X'X)$ equals the strong topology $\beta(X',X)$, this due to the reflexivity of nuclear Frechet spaces and has nothing to do with 0.4.4 in Bonet and Perez-Carreras which is about l.c.s. with the finest locally convex topology.

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Questions of this type were investigated in detail during the golden age of lcs‘s.  Your problem was usually discussed in the dual formulation: let $F$ be a closed subspace of a lcs $E$. Is every bounded  subset in the quotient space $E/F$ the image of such a subset of $E$?  This is is true when $E$ is a Fréchet space, but not, in general, for $DF$-spaces, these being the two principal generalisations of Banach spaces. Unfortunately, I can‘t give precise references since at the moment I don‘t have access to the basic monographs but those of Grothendieck (who studied such questions in some detail) and Köthe are certainly suitable sources.

Comment: It is not true that every bounded set in the quotient of a Frechet space is contained in the image under the quotient map of a bounded set. In this context Grothendieck's definition of quasinormable spaces is highly relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I got it the wrong way round.  I think (hope) it is true for $DF$-spaces but can‘t check the sources for the moment. At least what I said is true for compact sets and so the OP‘s question has a positive solution for the duals of Fréchet Montel spaces.

Comment: No,  this is neither true for DF- and even LB-spaces. And even if a  quotient of an LB-space lifts bounded sets it need not lift compact sets.